# When will Elsa 2.0 be released?

Tags: elsa-workflows

Just looking at using Elsa for my workflow implementation.

What is the timeline for 2.0?  I read that it was slated for end of March - any updates?

Thanks!

Martin

Comment: Hey, I had the same question. The answer is: 'Look at the milestones' :), Each Github repo has Issues, and you can sort them by Label or Milestone. The maintainer of the Elsa core repo maintain the Milestones like every day. [Milestones](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/milestones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was originally slated for end of March, but then got delayed to end of April. Elsa 2.0-RC2 was just made available on NuGet, so we're getting close to an official 2,0 release. We're currently focused on documentation, bug fixing and polishing. Realistically speaking I am hoping to release 2.0 sometime before the end of May, but we will see.

Comment: Thanks Sipke - looking forward to the new release.